# D3 bounded dragging

Tags: d3.js

What I have is a draggable line inside an SVG (about 300px). My objective is to restrict how far the line can move so it doesn't get outside of my SVG. I am about an hour into using d3 so any help is appreciated.

I've tried using some if statements earlier but none of them worked. Here's my code:

```
var svg = document.getElementById("probabilityDensitySVG");
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('dragstart', null)
    .on('drag', function(d){
var dx = d3.event.dx;
var dy = d3.event.dy;
var x1New = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('x1'))+ dx;
var y1New = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('y1'));
var x2New = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('x2'))+ dx;
var y2New = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('y2'));
line.attr("x1",x1New)
 .attr("y1",y1New)
 .attr("x2",x2New)
 .attr("y2",y2New);
}).on('dragend', function(){
}); 

var line = d3.select(svg)
  .append("line")
  .attr("x1",100)
  .attr("y1",143)
  .attr("x2",100)
  .attr("y2",370)
  .attr("stroke-width",5)
  .attr("stroke","black")
  .call(drag);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested ternary operator to check the boundaries.

For instance, limiting the drag between `50` and `300` in the x coordinate:

```
x1New = dx > 300 ? 300 : dx < 50 ? 50 : dx;
```

Here is the demo (I'm using `d3.event.x` instead of `d3.event.dx`):

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on('dragstart', null)
  .on('drag', function(d) {
    var dx = d3.event.x;
    x1New = dx > 300 ? 300 : dx < 50 ? 50 : dx;
    line.attr("x1", x1New)
      .attr("x2", x1New);
  }).on('dragend', function() {});

var line = svg.append("line")
  .attr("x1", 100)
  .attr("y1", 10)
  .attr("x2", 100)
  .attr("y2", 90)
  .attr("stroke-width", 5)
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .call(drag);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="350" height="100"></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. An example of the syntax is very helpful.

Comment: @allegro I see that you posted another question, and that you are quite new at S.O.. So, here is a tip: unless you acknowledge a useful answer, people will stop answering questions from you (I mean, that's what I normally do).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! It has been a while since I started going back on SO.